# Publishing .NET MAUI app in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio, maui, visual-studio-mac

I'm using Visual Studio for Mac 17.4 (Build 2406) and trying to create a package that I can upload to AppStore.

I'm not sure if we can now use Visual Studio to do this or we still need to use the termainal.

This is a .NET 7 based .NET MAUI app so I modified the command I used to use to create a package but it's giving me an error.

The command I used in termainal is:

```
dotnet publish -f:net7.0-ios -c:Release
```

This gives me the following error:

> A runtime identifier must be specified in order to publish this

What am I missing here?

Comment: dotnet publish -c Release -f:net7.0-androi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like, we still create the package through .NET CLI using the following command -- notice the addition of runtime identifier:

```
dotnet publish -f:net7.0-ios -c:Release /p:RuntimeIdentifier=ios-arm64
```

Comment: As far as I know the tooling in Visual Studio hasn't catched up yet. If you want to publish you still need to use the command-line as you already found out. The full guide is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/overview?view=net-maui-7.0

Answer (score 0):

I am answering it late. But I just recently created a MAUI app and deployed to Google store and Apple store using VS 2022 and .NET core 7.
Visual Studio is good to create .aab, apk and ipac files. it also creates .exe for windows.
there are chalenges in creating image icons and setting the plist file. however, if you fillup all the values correctly, VS handles it quite well.

1. use any free tool to create all size icons
2. use the correct store key and alias when creating .aab or package file for android
3. need to add correct info the build package in the plist when creating ipac file.
4. i have to manually add ios-arm64 in the project file.

Hopefully you will be able to build after taking care if the above 4 points.

Answer (score 0):

dotnet publish -c Release -f:net7.0-android